# wso2 unable to locate the specified wsdl from registry

Tags: wso2-esb

ok, here we go. The issue is that with my proxy service i click design view, publish wsdl from registry, i pick the wsdl that i have loaded into the registry, then attempt to save the proxy but get the following error:

```
Couldn't build the proxy service : gasd_lookup. Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin}
```

org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ProxyAdminException: Error trying to add the proxy service to the ESB configuration : gasd_lookup :: Couldn't build the proxy service : gasd_lookup. Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service

Naturally this is fairly annoying as i have selected the resource from the registry via the web gui so its obviously there...

Here is my setup:
wso2esb 4.6.0
service code comes from gov registry 4.5.3 via deployment synchronizer
custom cert is used
connected to BAM 2.2.0

Comment: I added debug to logs and have seen this error but not sure why registry would be unavailable: DEBUG -  Will not  evaluate the value of the remote entry with a key gov:/trunk/gasd_lookup.wsdl,  because the registry is not available {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got rid of the above error in my comment by enabling caching, after this i was able to see the real error, which was logged as debug unfortunately. The error was :

```
 faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Encountered illegal extension element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}porttype'
```

When i took the wsdl from chrome and saved it, chrome had automatically changed some of the camel casing to lower case. This is a chrome bug.

Naturally the initial error reported by wso2 was entirely incorrect, as it did find the file in the registry but it was invalid.

Comment: I created a Jira on this, so the error log will be improved to be more specific: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3856

Answer (score 0):

Same error message here. Perhaps a quicker solution: I used WSO2 Developer Studio to validate the project WSDL's which identifies the problem soon enough. 
(Go to the WSDL, right-click, "validate", and your error appears in the problem view)