# Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service - WS02

Tags: wsdl

I referred the link:
[wso2 unable to locate the specified wsdl from registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025038/wso2-unable-to-locate-the-specified-wsdl-from-registry)

But it did not solve my issue. The issue is  that I have .wsdl file that has a large set of .xsd files associated with it. I basically zipped the files up in a directory and saved the it as a .gar file (with the base .wsdl file in the root). then I uploaded the file in the registry on the ESB. Then I modified my service proxy to point to registry entry that points to the .gar (wsdl files). When I try to build and deploy.. I get the error:
Unable to locate the specified WSDL to build the service 
Any ideas ?

Comment: what is the WSO2 ESB version you are using ? have you installed governance features on ESB to make it enable to upload .gar files ?

Comment: Version 4.90 (The latest download). I put in a support ticket and they recommended as opposed to uploading the .gar file to to registry using the ESB interface, adding a "Governance Registry Artifact" project and then creating a .CAR file archive to upload to the ESB. I will comment on this if it works on a later post